# onclick() javascript attribute staying in check with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a pretty simple javascript program here that changes the image of another image on click to show that it is selected, however i can not seem to be capable of keeping it in sync with my check boxes, occasionally it will come off sync and cause issues with my php form

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func()
{
    var img1= document.getElementById("img1");

    if(img1.name == "on")
    {
        img1.src = "images/" + "img1a.jpg";
        img1.name = "off";
    }
    else
    {
        img1.src = "images/" + "img1.jpg";
        img1.name = "on";
    }
}
</script>



</head>

<body>
<form>
<p align="center">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest1" id="interest1" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest2" id="interest2" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest3" id="interest3" value="x"></p>   
<p align="center">
<label for="interest1" id="label-interest1"><img src="images/img1.jpg" width="781" height="800" onclick="func()" id="img1" /></label>
<label for="interest2" id="label-interest2"><img src="/images/img2.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label>
<label for="interest3" id="label-interest3"><img src="/images/img3.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label></P><!-- code making checkbox be an image-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking `if(img1.name == "on")`, you can check the `checkbox.checked` state of the corresponding checkbox.

**EDIT:** For kicks and giggles, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3C6e/2/) example using jQuery.

Comment: I've heard that will work, but i cant seem to find anywhere explaining how it works. any pointers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it"? `checkbox.checked` is true when checked and false when not.

Comment: I mean like, i can't find how to use it as far as syntax goes, JS is by no means my "native" language

Comment: any chance you can explain this to me?